# Not able to run yq commands via rundeck job definitions

Tags: rundeck, yq

I installed snap package of `yq` and it is showing under `/home/ubuntu/` I want to convert `yaml file to json using yq`. I used  this command `cat file.yaml | yq . -o=json > file.json` to convert the file under location `/home/ubuntu/` and this command is working when I run via command line.
But if I try to run this same command in bash shell script in my rundeck job definition, its giving below error.

```
Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details
```

My Rundeck version is `Rundeck 2.6.9-1` and it is running on ubuntu 18

Comment: Have you considered installing yq natively rather than via Snapcraft? It's the sandboxing that's messing you up here; install it in a way that doesn't put it inside a sandboxed wrapper and the issue is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

I [reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O93BK.jpg) your issue, and it's a snap package limitation (described [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/support-for-non-home-homedirs/11209) and also commented by Charles Duffy in your original question), Rundeck home it's defined at `/var/lib/rundeck` path.

So, the best way is to uninstall the snap yq package (as root: `snap remove yq`) and install it in the traditional way:

As root:

1. Download and put the `yq` binary in the `/usr/local/bin` path:

`wget -qO /usr/local/bin/yq https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64`

2. Give it the rights permissions:

`chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/yq`

Then, your job should [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc68n.jpg).

Comment: I tried giving the full path of `yq` in my script. Its giving same error

Comment: yes I found the root cause. Even I realised it is limitation of snap package. So I removed `yq` snap package and followed usual method to install it. thank you!